# Existence of affine hull of set S

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

"Obviously, the intersection of an arbitrary collection of affine sets is again affine. Therefore, given any $S \subset R^{n}$ there exists a unique smallest affine set containing $S$ (namely, the intersection of collection of affine sets M such that $S \subset M$. This is called the affine hull of S. "

This is a paragraph from "convex analysis" by rockafeller (page - 6). My question is why, given every $S \subset R^{n}$ there exists a unique smallest affine set containing S ? Why it should be so ? (just to clear another doubt, is $S$ here any subset of $R^n$ or does it mean only subspace of $R^n$? Nothing is mentioned in the book)

Comment: You take the intersection of every affine subspaces that contain $S$

Comment: From theorem, I know that corresponding to every affine sets there exists a parallel subspace. But I am not aware of theorem that says  affine sets contain subspaces.